# PostgreSQL Services

Tags: postgresql, service, systemctl

Can someone give a detailed explanation of how the `postgresql` service(s) works on Ubuntu [16.04]? The behavior that leads me to ask is the following. I use the command `sudo systemctl start postgresql` to start my postgresql service. When I run `systemctl list-units | grep post` I see

```
UNIT                           LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION
postgresql.service             loaded active exited    PostgreSQL RDBMS
postgresql@9.6-main.service    loaded active running   PostgreSQL Cluster 9.6-main
system-postgresql.slice        loaded active active    system-postgresql.slice
```

and when I run `sudo systemctl stop postgresql` both `postgresql.service` *and* `postgresql@9.6-main.service` disappear. What is each of these three services doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `postgresql@9.6-main.service` is registered service for `PostgreSQL Cluster 9.6-main` cluster. This is the one that actually controls postgres on your system.

I assume `postgresql.service` [is the effect desribed here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241979)

I assume `system-postgresql.slice` [is a postgres slice unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.slice.html)

none of above are critical for running postgres. You can start/stop the cluser with just `pg_ctl`, without registering it with your services. But if you wonder which service runs it in your case - then it is `postgresql@9.6-main.service`